# AEM - Custom implementation on We Retail site

Tags: java, apache, adobe, aem, licensing

I am trying to do a **comparison of different search engines in Adobe Experience Manager**.

Since I would like to avoid creating a lot of content (which is needed for such task) and frontend part, I would like to implement these search engines on custom components on AEM's reference site - **We Retail**.

> We Retail is open source and it can be found here:
>   https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail

When I download project on my local machine, it works fine when it is deployed on running AEM 6.4 instance. The problem occurs when I try to make any custom code or **modification** to the core package.

For example I wanted to extend core search servlet, but it does not work. Even when I create empty Java class, it can not be built because of the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.12:check (default) on project we.retail.core: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: /Users/.../we-retail/core/target/rat.txt -> [Help 1]
```

Now I am interested in following questions:

- Has someone else made any **custom implementation on We Retail
  project**? Did anyone had similar issue?
- Is it possible that Adobe forbids any implementation with these
  *licences*, and if so, why would they do it if I have bought licence and project is *open source*?
- Is there some email which I can contact regarding permission to
  implement search engines on We Retail project?
- Is there any similar site that I can work on?
- Did anyone had any similar problems regarding usage of AEM Java core components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build fails because their POM declares [Apache RAT plugin](https://creadur.apache.org/rat/apache-rat-plugin/check-mojo.html) to check for license headers in all files. Either remove the plugin from POM or copy paste the license header in your file.

They are just enforcing all their code to contain relevant license information. You are still free to use it as per terms of license mentioned at https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail/blob/master/LICENSE